# Krull-Schmidt theorem and internally cancellable modules?

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, modules, algebras

According to [this](http://pages.uoregon.edu/brundan/math607winter03/ch2.pdf) lecture notes (in Lemma2.1) the statement $Ae\simeq Ae^{\prime}\to A(1-e)\simeq A(1-e^{\prime})$ is true for finite dimensional algebras by using Krull-Schmidt theorem. Can anyone please give me hint about that.

Comment: @rschwieb I also found a counterexample [here](http://math.berkeley.edu/~lam/html/JAlg-ICring.pdf) example 2.1 the second one, that is why I deleted it.

Comment: Thanks for reopening it. Glancing at the link, I think the example I'm giving is different from the ones given there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Krull-Schmidt theorem literally says:

> If you decompose a module with finite composition length into a direct sum of indecomposables in two ways, then the two decompositions are the same length, and there's some permutation that pairs up factors from each decomposition into isomorphic pairs.

So the idea is that you take the two decompositions $Ae\oplus A(1-e)=A=Ae'\oplus A(1-e')$ and refine the summands into indecomposable modules. Since the pieces in $Ae$ and $Ae'$ pair up, the pieces in $A(1-e)$ and $A(1-e')$ pair up into isomorphic pairs. Thus their sums are isomorphic.